# why does $.post() work but not fetch work

Tags: ajax, authentication, fetch

I am just trying to convert my ajax code into fetch but fetch just doesn't seem to work.

1. Why is that?
2. How can I fix it?
3. I can provide more info if needed.

Here is my js code:

```
fetch("login.php", {
method: "POST",
body: JSON.stringify(data),
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
},
}).then(response => 
{
    response.clone().text().then(resp => 
    {
        console.log(resp);
        if(resp.trim()=="ok")
        {
            window.location = "tab.html";
        }
    })
});
//ajax code underneath that's the same but works
$.post("login.php", {username: $("#user").val(), password: $("#password").val()}).done(function(response)
{
    console.log(response);
    if(response.trim()=="ok")
    {
        window.location = "tab.html";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I might answer this one. Took a while to figure out but got there in the end. Just use the form data method like so:

```
let data = new FormData;
data.append("user", $("#user").val());
data.append("password", $("#password").val());
fetch("login.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: data,
}).then(response => 
{
    response.text().then(text => 
    {
        console.log(text); 
        if(text.trim() == "ok")
        {
            window.location = "tab.html";
        }
    })
});`
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, didn't think of that tried lots of methods but not this. I am guessing the same principal applies to signup as well